# Replace multiple occurrences of one character with different characters in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string with this format `abc-123-def` and I want to replace the first "-" with "_" and the second "-" with "." We cannot predict the value of the "123" part and the "def" part.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Use `String.replaceFirst()` in a loop.

Comment: Split the `String` on `-` and the reconstrictue the resulting array the way you want?

Comment: Is the length of def and 123 always 3? What about abc?

Comment: yes. actually it is dot separated digits  eg: 1.2.3

Comment: @ Codebender  how to use replaceFirst ? could you please bit explain ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use replacefirst in a loop.

```
String[] replacements = {"_", "."};
String str = "abc-123-def";

for (String replacement : replacements) {
    str = str.replaceFirst("-", replacement);
}
```

This will replace each `-` in the order of replacements array.

---

Or, if you prefer using java 8 kung fu:

```
str = Stream.of("_", ".").reduce(str, (a, b) -> a.replaceFirst("-", b));
```

Comment: Thanks! This would be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:
String str = "abc-123-def";

str.replaceFirst("-","_").replaceFirst("-",".");